# How did they shoot the Black & White scenes in Jackie (2016)?

Tags: production, jackie

How did they shoot the Black & White scenes in [***Jackie***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1619029/) (2016)?

[image]

With the movie releasing in 2016, how did they accomplish the 1960s feel?

Comment: You might want to think about [**merging accounts**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: I think that Windows Movie Maker also can do it ...

Comment: You know, the cameras from the 60s still exist...

Answer (score 4):

### They were shot in Black & White

Madeline Fontaine (Costume Designer) told [**The Hollywood Reporter**](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/jackie-costume-designer-dressing-natalie-portman-as-first-lady-950069)

> The red dress she wore during the [Charles] Collingwood's interview in the White House was originally from Dior. We found the right fabric, made the right color after some camera tests. **We even had to make a pink version for the scenes shot in black-and-white, to match with the footage** — the red was too dark. I'm not sure which house designed the black outfit she wears at the funeral, but we made that, too.

It's likely that any graininess was added later digitally in post-production.